# Spring.net NMS vs Apache NMS

Tags: activemq-classic, spring.net, nms

I was looking using ActiveMQ and I found that spring.net has it's own NMS library and so does the Apache community

http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/nms-quickstart.html
http://activemq.apache.org/nms/nms-api.html

Does anyone know anything about them?

Answer (score 2):

Spring.NET is using the Apache.NMS libraries underneath, just like the regular Spring JMSTemplate etc uses watch JMS provider you configure.  From what I recall the Spring.NET release is using an older version of NMS.ActiveMQ by default.  So if you want to use the most up to date ActiveMQ .NET library than you'd have to go with straight Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ or figure out how to wire in the alter libs into the Spring.NET stuff.

Comment: Dunno if this is any help, but Spring.NET v2 is out in a matter of days now. They might have updated their libs to the latest version.